# Exception in hibernate: Unable to create requested service

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've already gone through the various response and spent quite a couple of hours to resolve this issue. Requesting your help.

I'm writing the first program in hibernate and have referred javatpoint, luv2code and various other sites. Everyone explains quite similarly, but the issue I'm facing isn't answered.

Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "com.info.Employee" table ="empl">
<id name="id">
<generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>

<property name = "fname"></property>
<property name = "lname"></property>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
<property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.driver</property>
<property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLdialect</property>
<property name = "connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_student?useSSL=false</property>
<property name = "connection.username">hbstudent</property>
<property name = "connection.password">hbstudent</property>


<mapping resource = "Employee.hbm.xml"></mapping>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error received:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at com.info.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
    ... 24 more
```

The mysql-connector jar file is also added to the Build path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4MF3.png)

Comment: Java class names usually starts with uppercase letter. `<property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>`

Comment: Thanks @Tijkijiki for noticing it. It helped a lot.

Comment: There were a few more errors...like <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

Comment: @Tijkijiki the same error s received while I tried an example using HIbernate annotations. I have updated the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file and the previous program runs successfully. Now, while trying with annotations, a similar issue arises for the same cfg.xml file.